# Ubuntu 14.04.LTS problem with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem with Ubuntu 64 bits 14.04.LTS After using " sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full or only using :sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full " I get error this. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I try to solve this problem by following these below command in Terminal: sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

But still I get same Error in Ubuntu 14.04.LTS system. Could any body give any helpful tips to get rid of this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225584/ubuntu-14.04.lts-problem-with-ros/) by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric is very old; it shouldn't be possible to install it on Ubuntu 14.04. Did you upgrade this computer from a previous version of Ubuntu?

On 14.04, the recommended ROS versions are Indigo and Jade.

It sounds like apt is in a bad state on your computer; some kind of package conflict.  Sometimes `sudo apt-get install -f` can fix this automatically, but usually it requires some manual work. If you **edit** your question to include the full error message from apt, and some more information about how you got here, I can help you debug further.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4